# Flash simulate mp3 streaming

Tags: flash, audio-streaming

Is it possible to simulate streaming mp3s with local mp3s in flash?

Answer (score 0):

If the swf is loaded locally then it can load local mp3s.  If the swf is from the web, then the mp3s also have to come from the web (or have a valid cross domain file for another host).

Comment: OK, so you suggest to load my mp3s from a web server? But after a while they are cached...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of the player you can use Flash IDE to test the streaming locally.

Load the main FLA, then Contreol->TestMovie, when it compiles go to View->Simulate Download.

You can also open the View->Bandwidth profiler or change the speed settings in View->Download Settings.

Comment: I am using the simulate download but it works only for the player not for the mp3s